# Date Conversion in Excel via Python

Tags: python, excel

I am working with .csv dataset that I download from an online source.  There are two date columns in the file that come in a custom excel format of "d-mmm", but when you highlight over a cell it shows the contents of the cell in "mm/dd/yyyy" format (this is in the formula box, not the cell itself).

Picture to illustrate my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpTzQ.jpg

I'm struggling with getting the correct date format in python without manually changing the data type in excel.

Like stated, I have tried to manually change the data types and this works...but then I would have to do this in 15 different .csvs and whenever I update the .csvs, I would have to repeat the process.

I have also tried using parse_dates and date_parser in my pandas read_csv, but haven't had any luck

Ideally, there would be some process that would open up a .csv, read the contents of the two date fields, and convert from "d-mmm" (as shown) to "mm/dd/yyyy" as desired.

Is this possible or would I have to manually change data types within excel?

Comment: how are you loading your CSV in python? Pandas? Can you share couple lines from the CSV, and the python code?

Comment: shouldn't this be like directly loaded ? I mean, if you have the 'text' (data) in "mm/dd/yyyy" format, then it's as easy as just parse the text into a datetime.datetime class, isnt it? EDIT: by the way, could you give a link to the csv file ? (if it's CSV, why are you loading it in excel?)

Comment: Your Question is contradict: `CSV` does not have any formating like `"d-mmm"`. You are dealing either with `.xlsx` or your Excel uses `"d-mmm"` as the default format.

Comment: @BarisTasdelen sure, it's `df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='latin-1)`.  I can't share any lines as this is confidential information, even if I were to sanitize it.

Comment: @tglaria You would think it could be directly loaded, but directly loading it does not give me the correct format for the date.  The issue is that the csv is saving the field in a "d-mmm" format but the meta data itself is in "dd/mm/yyyy" when opened in excel.  Unfortunately I can't give you even a sanitized version of my file because it is confidential.  I could see if I could replicate in a new excel file

Comment: @stovfl You're absolutely right, csv does not have a "d-mmm" format.  That's an excel feature.  One thing I forgot to mention, when I download my file, it comes in unicode text format, which I open in excel and save as a csv.  Could this be causing my issue?  Because I opened in excel it defaulted the date fields to "d-mmm" instead of the source format of "dd/mm/yyyy"?

Comment: @wisniemj: *"it comes in unicode text format"*: You can save as `CSV` using Python. Verify the `date` columns before rewriting with Exel. Does it look like `2019-03-28` or `1234456.789`?